# Can a battlefist be broken by normal means?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, artificer

I am playing an Artificer, Mastermaker subclass (from [Keith Barkers Dread Metrol Ravenloft/Eberron crossover](https://www.enworld.org/threads/dread-metrol-from-keith-baker-is-here.681348/)), and for roleplaying purposes want my character's battlefist be unrepairable owing to constant blunt and firework damage. Is that something I can do? I just want to pound it home how big the war is.

The link to the subclass wiki: http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/artificer:mastermaker

Comment: What system is this? D&D 5e, or some other system?

Comment: 5e, mastermaker subclass.

Comment: http://dnd5e.wikidot.com/artificer:mastermaker

Answer (score 6):

### Your battlefist doesn't need repair, but you can roleplay it does

5e normally does not have mechanics for your weapons or armor requiring repair. Other than in some other roleplaying systems, attacking with a weapon under normal circumstances will never damage or break it. Even the rules for long rests do not mention anything about maintenance on your weapons and armor, and that would normally be the time when player characters do things like sharpen their weapons, polish their armor and in general tend to their equipment.

Your **[Battlefist](https://www.dmsguild.com/m/product/364000)** is no different. There is nothing in its description that suggests it could break or require repair or maintenance. So, it would be hard to think of a situation where your battlefist would not work, from a game mechanics standpoint. As it is never really broken, you have to be creative to roleplay how you are unable to get it to work.

One approach is of course to just not use it from time to time, and claim it is broken due to heavy use. You can easily do that, but it would deprive you of some the use of an important class feature, weakening your character. That may be OK if you enjoy playing like that.

Another approach you could take is to make use of the higher level features of your class: at fifth level, you get to make an extra attack with the fist, at 9th you can add more infusions or use it as a shield.

If you are not yet high enough level, you could roleplay it as if your fist already has these features, but they are broken due to all the fighting you do, and no matter how hard you work to get them to work again, you just cannot do it. Then, when you reach 5th or 9th level, and gain those features, the in-narrative explanation is that you finally succeeded in "repairing" them back to functionality. That has no impact on the mechanics, but the flavor is what you are looking for.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147993/discussion-on-answer-by-nobody-the-hobgoblin-can-a-battlefist-be-broken-by-norma); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.